# Add to browser History without changing current URL

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have a 3 step signup process where each step is shown on the page using javascript without a page refresh. What I am trying to do now is add a back reference to what step the user was on so if they click the browser back button they will not lose all of their progress.

So for example, as the user navigates from Step 2 to Step 3 the URL stays at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). The user then clicks the browser back button. The URL should now be [www.example.com?step-2](http://www.example.com?step-2).

I'm thinking that I will somehow need to use the History API to accomplish this but if I use window.history.pushState(null, null, 'www.example.com?step-2'), the current URL would be changed as well.

How would I accomplish adding to the history without changing the current URL?

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to not change the URL, but to still allow back and forth history state changes, your best bet would be to utilize the window's `hashchange` event listener. This would of course utilize hash references within the URL, but the base URL won't change:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
  if (location.hash === '#step-2') {
    // Do something here
  }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

For further info on this, refer to official documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

Comment: Our hope was to maintain the illusion of nothing changing in the URL at all from step to step. Though if that ends up not being possible this is something we may end up having to do. Thanks.